# OpenVPN Connection very slow. Server located in Hong Kong, and Client Desktop is in New York

Tags: vpn, performance, openvpn, network-speed

I have a OpenVPN vps server in Hong Kong. The specs is just 1 Core 2.2ghz CPU and 1GB of RAM. The connection is a 100mbit. But when I connect from my desktop in NY, my speed is only 1-2mbit only. I'm pretty sure my config files are not optimized somehow for this long distance connection.

My objective here is for speed and I don't care about security, which is why I disabled all the tls-ciphers and encryption related settings. The main use of this connection is to stream video. So I'm not sure if I need compression or not.

Also what should my MTU be and what other settings should go along with it? Assuming this will improve my speed.

My OpenVPN Server settings:

```
port 10111
proto udp
dev tun
user nobody
group nobody
persist-key
persist-tun
keepalive 10 120
topology subnet
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
sndbuf 393216
rcvbuf 393216
push "sndbuf 393216"
push "rcvbuf 393216"
push "dhcp-option DNS 1.0.0.1"
push "dhcp-option DNS 1.1.1.1"
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
dh none
ecdh-curve prime256v1
crl-verify crl.pem
ca ca.crt
cert server_IzA1QdFzHLRFfEoQ.crt
key server_IzA1QdFzHLRFfEoQ.key
auth SHA256
status /var/log/openvpn/status.log
verb 3
```

And my client ovpn settings:

```
client
proto udp
remote xxxx.xx 10111
dev tun
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
remote-cert-tls server
verify-x509-name server_IzA1QdFzHLRFfEoQ name
auth SHA256
auth-nocache
setenv opt block-outside-dns # Prevent Windows 10 DNS leak
verb 3
```

Also here is the output of my OpenVPN when connected. I'm using a DDWRT router to make the connection:

[image]

Comment: What is the latency between the two servers and is there any packet loss?

Comment: And what country are you streaming video from?

Comment: hong kong. @MichaelHampton -- how do i check for packet loss and how can I prevent the loss?

Comment: I'd start by running mtr on your VPN server's public IP address, while not connected to the VPN.